# Getting accurate results from Google Places Library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) to search any type of nearby places by keyword within a [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) rectangle.

For example if I search for [pancakes](http://pamelasproducts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Pancakes.jpg) I'll get restaurants with pancakes on their menu but it will also throw in an establishment with no relation like a juice bar.

How can I get the most accurate results by providing only a keyword? My nearby search request looks like this:

```
var request = {
    bounds: my_bounds, //The bounds within which to search for places
    keyword: document.getElementById("keyword").value,
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE
};
```

I know that I can also specify a [type](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) in the request but that means that the user will have to choose an option from a list of types and I wish to keep search options as minimal as possible. Any kind advice is welcomed!

Comment: How would you expect to get an accurate result without specifying accurate search-criteria. When a user searches only for "pancake" also a software-store which sells a software named "pancake" will be a proper result. The only thing I can imagine is a database with predefined keyword-type-relations, but you'll never know for what the users are really searching for(food or software) when you don't let them specify it.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I just thought of one way to do it. How about getting the prominent type from all results and excluding any place that isn't listed under that type? For example if "pancake" returns mostly places with type = "food" and one is "software", take it out.

Comment: It's meant for general searches not very specific.

Comment: That's possible, you must first iterate over the results to get the "ranking" of the types(filter out basic types likes e.g. establishment). Then iterate again over the results and return only the results with the most used type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really being selfish here and trying to find an answer to my post - but this question may be related and someone may be able to shine some more light on it for both of us.

I have noticed on a normal Google maps search (i.e. manually in a browser) if I search for: xxxxxx loc: yyyyyyyyyy where xxxxxx is a category such as "university" and yyyyyyyyyy (note the key "loc:" - for location in the middle) is the address I want to search around I get pretty accurate results. I just tested on "pancakes" and same thing. Also many of the sites have a "Category" which lists "pancakes" (or "university") that seems to show a closer match to what is wanted and/or that could be filtered on - better than using "type" or "name". This search also give distance to - which I want but which may not be important to you.

If anyone knows how to do such a "loc:" based search from the APIs that might be the answer to our questions (or maybe just mine)?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "loc" Could you show a clearer example?

Comment: loc is (I presume) short for "location". From what I can see it is primarily for putting in lat/lng numbers for a location rather than a text description but with a text description it also works and it works better than any other search I have found for what I want e.g. "university loc: Sydney Opera House, Sydney, New South Wales".

Comment: But I just tried it now and "university loc: Sydney Opera House, Sydney, New South Wales" and "university Sydney Opera House, Sydney, New South Wales" are giving me the same results. I had this first when I was searching about a month ago, then it seemed to break, then I found "loc:" and it worked great after that. Unless it is storing "loc:" in my cookies or something and still using it. Arrgggg. I don't know now!

Comment: What I do know is I can't get Google Places API to return these results! I've resulted to scraping the pages for now.

Comment: The Places Library shows every option that you can use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches as far as i know, searches doesn't return a category. Only type which is practically the same thing.

Comment: The places service also returns detailed information about a place https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details